# How to Track batch packages are worked

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools

Have more than five packages in my **SSIS** project. Face difficulties to run packages batch, Fail to track which package is not running, Which one is failed, Which one is a success. Re-run package batch how to set failed package start point.

Comment: Doesn't the log tell you?

Comment: in sql server, go to `Integration services catalog -> SSISDB`. right click it `Reports -> Standard reports -> all execution reports`. Here you can see what all passed n failed.

Comment: @Prabhat G , use Standard reports how to set a package re-run start point?

Comment: My bad, I didn't read that. However, I use Checkpoint in SSIS to re-run failed packages.

Comment: @Prabhat G, Will you please describe how you set the Checkpoints?

Comment: you can read about it here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/sql-tools/implementing-checkpoints-in-an-ssis-package/

Answer (score 0):

**Manage Package Executions**

To manage Package runs, I prefer to do it with a SQL Server Table. I keep a table in SQL Server with columns like.

`PackageName , LastExecuted , Error , Intervals`

Create a Master Package, which reads data from this table and execute package depending on their LastExecuted and interval values.

Also execute package which errord out in their last execution so on and so forth, you get the idea.

**Manage Start Points for Re-Runs**

Well depending on what your source and destinations are it may differ. But when you are extracting from or loading to SQL Server, create a table in SQL Server with probably two columns.

`PK_ID , Status`

1. In the very first step of the package execution , upload the Primary key values of the rows with Status ID = 0 (Row Status Start).
2. Once the package execution starts set Set StatusID = 1 (Row Status Processing )
3. One the package execution has finished Set StatusID = 2 (Row Status Processed )
4. And finally in the very last step delete rows from that table with StatusID = 2 , Delete processed rows if anything is not deleted gets processed in next run .

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information, Something is not clear to me, Suppose there are two tables(Table-A, Table-B) in my database. One of my Package read data from Table-A and store in Table-B. In this package activity how I set your defined process 1,2,3,4.

Comment: @shamim if it is just an Extract and Load from SQL Server to SQL Server, then you need to find a way to get the delta data (new or different), I usually go with some sort of Date column to get the delta data. And also use some sort of holding/temp table in the destination server before you upload the data into actual destination, use  `UPSERT`    operation on the destination table from the holding/temp table. Just in case if there is anything that is already there it just gets updated and new stuff will get inserted.

Comment: I think your first approach is better because to hold data in temp table it’s really expensive moreover need to compare each and every record in UPSERT which is also expensive. Will you please tell me how I use 1,2,3,4 steps efficiently?

Comment: still stuck on this issue, will you please give some example about how to Manage Package Executions.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be too big a deal; you can simply restart the package after the problem has been resolved and everything is back to normal. Event-handlers and Server login help you to identify problems but need a process which helps to identify failed batches to manage Start Points for Re-Runs. In detail, the [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1231943/SSIS-custom-logging-to-manage-start-point-for-Re-R) describes re-run process.